# How to set the font from Styles.xml in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-styles

**What I have**:

1. I have a custom class inheriting `AppCompatTextView`.
2. I have defined a custom attribute `textformat` in `attires.xml` and
   i am passing what font I need to set from the xml

---

**Stylefile**

```
<style name="HeaderFilterName">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/back_button</item>
        <item name="android:text">@string/str_filter_edit</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/Header_Filter_Name_Text_size</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    </style>
```

***XML***

```
    <customViews.CustomTftTextView
    android:id="@+id/txtScreenNameId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:textformat="fonts/sf_san_fransisco.ttf"
    style="@style/HeaderFilterName"/>
```

**attr.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="customfont">
        <attr name="textformat" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**CustomTftTextView.java**

```
public class CustomTftTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
    private String text;

    public CustomTftTextView(final Context context) {
        this(context, null);
        Initialize(text,context);
    }

    public CustomTftTextView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        text = context.getResources().obtainAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.customfont).getString(R.styleable.customfont_textformat);
        Initialize(text,context);
    }

    public CustomTftTextView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        text = context.getResources().obtainAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.customfont).getString(R.styleable.customfont_textformat);
        Initialize(text,context);
    }

    private void Initialize(String format, Context context) {

        Typeface mTypeface;
        if (format != null)
        {
            mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), format);
        }
        else
        {
            mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/sf_san_fransisco.ttf");
        }
        setTypeface(mTypeface, Typeface.NORMAL);
        setLineSpacing(0.0f, 1.4f);
    }
}
```

---

### While above code works perfect, If I move `app:textformat` inside the `style` file, The font is not setting.

```
<style name="HeaderFilterName">
            <item name="android:src">@drawable/back_button</item>
            <item name="android:text">@string/str_filter_edit</item>
            <item name="textformat">@string/custom_font_medium </item>
<item name="android:gravity">center</item>
            <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/Header_Filter_Name_Text_size</item>
            <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        </style>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="custom_font_medium">fonts/sf_san_fransisco.ttf</string>
```

### How properly achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the docs for the [`Resources#obtainAttributes()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#obtainAttributes(android.util.AttributeSet,%20int[])), it says:

> Retrieve a set of basic attribute values from an AttributeSet, not performing styling of them using a theme and/or style resources.

To get the attributes with your style applied, use a `Context#obtainStyledAttributes()` method instead. It would also be advisable to keep a reference to that return, so you can `recycle()` it when done. For example:

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.customfont);
text = a.getString(R.styleable.customfont_textformat);
a.recycle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in styles.xml you used namespace like below

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto'>
```